# Reset the parameter in SSRS after operated an action?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have 2 SSRS reports that have been deployed to the report server.

Report 1 has action that allows the user to open a new window for Report 2.

Below is the example of my Report 1.

| Department | Success Count | Failure Count | Running Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Department 1 | 10 | 2 | 25 |
| Department 2 | 18 | 5 | 12 |

Report 2 is a drilldown report that shows all the details within that department.

The idea is when I click Department 1, it will show all Success/Failure/Running data within department 1

And when I click the number under the specific catalog, it will only shows the corresponding data.

For eg: If I click 10 on the first row under Success,  it will only shows the department 1 with success data.

What happening right now is when I click 10, it did show the success data within department 1,

However, If I click department 1 again, it still shows the department 1 with success.

(if I click department2, it would shows department 2 with success)

So my assumption is the parameter is not reset when I click the first column.

How do I reset my parameter on my SSRS?

I hope my explanation is clear enough to understand,  if you need more visual explanation, I can paste here.

Edit:
Attachment 1 Dataset for Drilldown Report 2

```
SELECT *  FROM [DASHBOARD].[dbo].[ENTERPRISE_LOGGING_SUMMARY]
WHERE [DEPARTMENT] = @DEPARTMENT AND 
TYPE1 = @TYPE AND
STATE =@State
```

Attachment 2 Action for Department column

```
       ="javascript:void window.open('" & Globals!ReportServerUrl
     & "/reportserver?" & Globals!ReportFolder & "/DrillDownReport&TYPE="&Fields!TYPE1.Value 
& "&DEPARTMENT=" &Fields!DEPARTMENT.Value & "','_blank','width=1500,height=750,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,toolbar=no,status=no,menu=no,top=20,left=15')"
```

Attachment 3 Action for STATE(Success/Failure/Running)

```
="javascript:void window.open('" & Globals!ReportServerUrl
 & "/reportserver?" & Globals!ReportFolder & "/DrillDownReport&rs:Command=Render&TYPE="&Fields!TYPE1.Value & 
 "&DEPARTMENT=" &Fields!DEPARTMENT.Value & 
 "&State=" & Fields!STATE.Value &"&rs:Command=Render','_blank','width=1500,height=750,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,toolbar=no,status=no,menu=no,top=20,left=15')"
```

Comment: You'll need to edit your question and show your drill down report parameters and also how each action is configured and the parameter setup for each action. I've done these kind of reports a lot and never had any issues.

Comment: Hey Alan, I have edited my question. Is there anything else I can provide that may be helpful. Please let me know I will edit my question again. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you drill down report only takes single values for parameters.

It looks like the department action is not sending the state parameter. So you could try setting it with something like

```
 ="javascript:void window.open('" & Globals!ReportServerUrl
     & "/reportserver?" & Globals!ReportFolder & "/DrillDownReport&TYPE="&Fields!TYPE1.Value 
& "&DEPARTMENT=" &Fields!DEPARTMENT.Value &     
& "&State=all" & "','_blank','width=1500,height=750,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,toolbar=no,status=no,menu=no,top=20,left=15')"
```

Then update the dataset query to something like this

```
SELECT *  FROM [DASHBOARD].[dbo].[ENTERPRISE_LOGGING_SUMMARY]
WHERE [DEPARTMENT] = @DEPARTMENT
AND TYPE1 = @TYPE 
AND (STATE =@State OR @State = 'all')
```

Comment: Thank you Sir. I think we are on the right track. But this still throw new an error. I guess i did not set 'all' properly.  Beside the 2 changes you mentioned above. Anywhere else i need to update this 'all' parameter?

Comment: I don't think so but you did not say it threw an error before. Show the error you are getting. I would also add a textbox, temporarily with the expression that causes the issue so you can see what it being generated. . I also =spotted a small error in my answer which I have updated changing `"&State=all" & "','_blank'` to `"&State=all" & ",'_blank'`

Comment: After i added the &State. it throw me an error "For more information about this error navigate to the report server on the local server machine, or enable remote errors" and also i think "&State=all" & "','_blank' (the original one) is the correct syntax. Cuz after i tried second one. it wont even open the new window report

Comment: I feel we are so close to this,  this def is the solution, i think i just have to configure this 'all' to somewhere else.    So after i add @State = 'all'  it will auto detect all parameter?  i dont need change anything else?

Comment: If the drill down report has "Available Values" set for the "State" parameter then you would have to add "all" as one of the available values. How is the Status parameter configured in the Drill Down report?

Comment: issue fixed, instead doing "&State = all"   i wrote "&State" = "all"  and boom    thanks for you help tho. U provided me the right path